# Angularjs - Function is undefined in child scope even though it is in the parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/vuN0zVhXNMHUEPMeRvRg?p=preview
In this plunkr, I call a directive which gets the function "test" from parent scope using the "&" operator.
Why when I try to use the function, it returns "undefined"?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p my-directive>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.test = function test(){
    alert('y');
  }
  console.log(angular.noop);
  console.log($scope.test);
});


app.directive('myDirective', [
    function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope: {
          value: '@', // some value
          test: '&' // the function
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          function functionName(func) {
            var ret = func.toString();
            ret = ret.substr('function '.length);
            ret = ret.substr(0, ret.indexOf('('));
            return ret;
          }
          console.log(scope.test());
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use isolated scope, you are defining a link between the parent scope and the directive scope *through attributes when the directive is declared*.

So, this code:

```
scope: {
          value: '@', // some value
          test: '&' // the function
        },
```

Is saying, "look for an attribute named `value` and `test` on the element on which the directive is declared."

So, it is expecting this:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p my-directive value="{{value}}" test="test()">Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>
```

For documentation see the "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" section of the [directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0):

Davin is absolutely right.

This would work exactly like you expect it, (alert pops up) when you use the remove the scope defined on the directive.

Here is your plunker fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/5T9ysjGPBfrhQXRuDGZA?p=preview that works.

By default the scope of a directive is inherited from the controller it is in; but by defining the scope attribute on the directive, you have created an "isoloated scope" that doesn't inherit from the controller.